# Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile ; Where is Error code meaning list?

Tags: symfony

I am reading [SYMFONY API doc about UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getError)

It explains getErrors() as such:

> If the upload was successful, the constant UPLOADERROK is returned.
>   Otherwise one of the other UPLOADERRXXX constants is returned.

I've tried to search  **UPLOADERROK** and **UPLOADERRXXX** it doesn't retrieve anything relevant.

Looking in the code of  "[my_symf_project]\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile" I've found the Constant name and their meaning:

```
/**
 * Returns an informative upload error message.
 *
 * @return string The error message regarding the specified error code
 */
public function getErrorMessage()
{
    static $errors = array(
        UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => 'The file "%s" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is %d KiB).',
        UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => 'The file "%s" exceeds the upload limit defined in your form.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => 'The file "%s" was only partially uploaded.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => 'No file was uploaded.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'The file "%s" could not be written on disk.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'File could not be uploaded: missing temporary directory.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => 'File upload was stopped by a PHP extension.',
    );

    $errorCode = $this->error;
    $maxFilesize = $errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE ? self::getMaxFilesize() / 1024 : 0;
    $message = isset($errors[$errorCode]) ? $errors[$errorCode] : 'The file "%s" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.';

    return sprintf($message, $this->getClientOriginalName(), $maxFilesize);
}
```

But I am not able to **find the code matching those constant**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the [built-in constants](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) provided by PHP.